# SFP for old, 200m fiber run

Tags: fiber, cabling, sfp

Fairly new with setting up fiber optic so bear with me.We have a single mode fiber optic running around 200m. After doing some research I have come down to purchasing this SFP: DLINK DEM310GT 1000BASE-LX MINI

My only main concern is that whether I need to consider other things which I read like wavelength or the OM of the fiber as our fiber is only running at 200 meters?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

OM ratings are for multi-mode fiber.  Single-mode fiber uses OS ratings and for a 200 meter run, the choice of OS rating should only be dependent on they type of installation (and should have been properly determined by your installer).

As for the wavelength this is determined by the transceiver, so you will be fine as long as you go with LX or LH transceivers for this run.  I prefer optics that support [digital optical monitoring](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/wireless/asr_901/Configuration/Guide/b_asr901-scg/b_asr901-scg_chapter_0101000.pdf) (DOM), if the platform (i.e. switch/router) also supports it as this will allow you to determine things like low/high power levels.  The linked product does not appear to have DOM support.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the fiber has been installed long ago we have no way to determine the OS rating. Would this SFP still workable?

Comment: It should work, but you don't specify the hardware platform, so there is no guarantee.  There are some hardware/SFP incompatibilities out there.

Comment: I'd be tempted to rent or borrow an optical fibre tester / OTDR to validate the interconnect and give you a figure of Attenuation